# TeX and how to not output the footline/headline on specific page

Tags: header-footer, tex-core, plain-tex, opmac, headline

The title page, any page, no head/footline using plain+etex+opmac, on a per page basis.

Is there a manual coding solution to a page macro to relax the foot/headline for the page. Below the "idea" not the solution apparently.

```
\tit Title % Some title command in plain tex

\def\nofootline{\footline{}} % would show an "empty" footline

\nofootline % the \nofootline is applied

\vfill\break % this would end the page

\let\nofootline{\relax} % no longer have the \nofootline having any effect
```

And the page at hoc would have a footline as defined originally.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are finding a macro like `\onlythispage`:

```
\def\onlythispage#1=#2{%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname saved\string#1\endcsname{\the#1}%
   \global#1={#2\global#1=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                           {\csname saved\string#1\endcsname}}
}
\def\nofootline{\onlythispage\footline={}} % would show an "empty" footline

\nofootline % the \nofootline is applied

Text, empty footline is here.

\vfill\break % this would end the page

Text, the original footline is here.

\end
```

Comment: The above code is fully functional.

Comment: The above code is fully functional. The \csname ...\endcsname , \the, \expandafter repetitions, \string in a single definition. A suggestion to learn from. Compact, concise solution.